# how to represent table with multivalued columns

Tags: java, mysql

How can I obtain the table structure as shown in the picture attached in Mysql?

[image]

Comment: You want to know how to make a table?

Comment: Please include your desired outcome *in the question itself*.  A link to an off-site image is not robust, indexable or convenient.  Also, show us what you've tried so far, and how your results differ from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like it will be 2 tables: a users table, and a prescriptions table with a one-to-many relationship between users and prescriptions. then you will use a join statement to get the data in the desired format.